# Get permalink from SKU

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do a reverse lookup to get the Permalink to a product from its SKU. The output of which will be used to redirect old URLS to new ones.

I am having trouble understanding the relationships between the tables used in woocommerce. The products seem to be stored in wp_posts, and the SKU in wp_wc_product_meta_lookup however when creating a join in the database tables this does not bring up the expected data :

```
SELECT pml.sku,pml.product_id,wpp.guid FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup pml LEFT JOIN wp_posts wpp ON wpp.ID=pml.product_id WHERE pml.stock_status='instock'
```

In addition to this the guid in wp_posts is not the same as the actual product URL - the categories are different.

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: The `SKU` is stored in the `postmeta` table - `meta_key` => `_sku`. The information for the product (it being a WordPress post) is stored in the `posts` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in WooCommerce function for this - [wc_get_product_id_by_sku](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product_id_by_sku.html#604-614).

Example:

```
<?php
echo get_permalink( wc_get_product_id_by_sku( 'SKU' ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The product post itself is stored in `wp_posts`, however `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` is actually a reference table that is used to speed up certain queries on the site. The actual SKU is stored in the `wp_postmeta` table under the `meta_key` of `_sku`. Here's an updated query that gets you Product ID and SKU:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value as `sku`,
       wp_posts.ID as `product_id`
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
       ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type LIKE 'product%'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sku'
```

Furthermore, you really should not us the GUID column for URLs. The GUID that Wordpress uses is a fake unique identifier that just shows the URL of the page on the environment it was created on. You are much better off creating a script that will generate the permalink for you via `get_permalink($post_id)`.